# NVMe-Dedicated Server without Virtualisation: Big speed benefit?

Tags: virtualization, openvz, dedicated-server, virtuozzo, nvme

I am currently using a VPS which is virtualised with Virtuozzo and sometimes my blog is starting to deliver in ***150ms till 350ms*** (server response).

I assume that the virtualisation is the bottle neck because as I read Virtuozzo does have only one Kernel which results also in performance issues. May I am wrong, I am not that expert, that's why I am asking here. ;)

A new idea grow in my head: I want to have my **wordpress blog** fast (500 unique visitors a day, and also running Confluence, JIRA and Nextcloud on that VPS). So what about renting a Dedicated Server with NVMe. A performance benefit would also be the Dedication and an extra One the NVMe SSD. What do you think about that? Or should I just look after a Hoster which is not using Virtuaozzo? What would you recommend instead?

I hope I can profit from your experience and knowledge.

Thank you! :)

frank

P.S.: On wordpress blogsite everything I know is done for page speed optimization. (Combining, minifying CSS/JS, optimizing pictures and so on...)

Comment: If you want to serve Wordpress fast, have a look into caching. Also: `Nginx` and `uwsgi`, communicating via a `uwsgi` socket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By considering random VPS vs dedicated server with NVMe storage, you are comparing a ride on a bus with buying a sportcar.

And no, Virtuozzo, implementing container virtualization here aren't the bottleneck. Instead containers usually introduce less overhead over full virtualization technologies.

But as you are renting the VPS your don't really have control over the physical node. And can't even know how much it's subsystems like I/O and CPU are loaded. Overselling VPS are pretty common practice, especially with cheap VPS. I mean the things inside your VPS/container might be optimized but you are getting the latency because other customers on the same physical node are overloading it's I/O or CPU. But it has nothing to do with Virtuaozzo itself.

Contrary to that a dedicated server will give you full control over the resources there. So you will exactly know your resource usage.

But something like wordpress blog with 500 visitors/day shouldn't require a dedicated server to run smoothly. You can check & test other VPS providers. Just make to sure to rent from a reliable provider who won't oversell their nodes.

Comment: A nvme backed VPS at amazon EC2 can be the Ferrari of sportcars.
You might be right about his particular solution but the time where virtual servers sucked is history.

Comment: @John as I already stated in my answer year ago that was about particular "random" VPS OP was using. And as I said in conclusion that reliable VPS provider milage may vary.